# Is it bad to inject ModelMapper bean into a DTO for an entity containing a set of other entities? (Builder)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, design-patterns

Is it bad to inject ModelMapper bean into a DTO for a class containing a set of other objects? (Builder)
Hello

I have a JPA entity User with a u/OneToMany relation to UserStats, I have made DTO's for both of these and have used the Lombok builder annotation.

I am wondering if doing:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
UserDTO {

@Autowired
ModelMapper modelMapper;

private String username;

private String password;

@JsonIgnore
private Integer totalGamesPlayed = 0;

@JsonIgnore
String highestAchievedLeagueType = "bronze";


UserStatsDTO userStatsDTO = UserStatsDTO.builder()
.isLeagueUserStats(false)
.build();
UserStatsDTO leagueUserStatsDTO = UserStatsDTO.builder()
.isLeagueUserStats(true)
.build();

UserStats innerUserStats = modelMapper.map(userStatsDTO, UserStats.class);
UserStats leagueUserStats = modelMapper.map(leagueUserStatsDTO, UserStats.class);
//array of strings
UserStats[] userStatsArray = {innerUserStats, leagueUserStats};
private List<UserStats> userStats = Arrays.asList(userStatsArray);

}
```

Is bad practice? I mean, if not I will have to set it myself within the service layer?

Answer (score 0):

It is bad to inject `ModelMapper` bean into a DTO. It is not flexible.
DTO object should:

- be simple as much as possible.
  DTOs normally are created as POJOs. They are flat data structures that contain no business logic. They only contain storage, accessors and eventually methods related to serialization.
- be decoupled from the domain or persistence objects.
  We can build different views from our domain models, allowing us to create other representations of the same domain but optimizing them to the clients' needs without affecting our domain design. Mapper component that transfers the data, making sure that both DTO and domain model don't need to know about each other. In your example, DTO know about persistence object, it needs to be decoupled.

See an example of good design: [Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)